# Querying specific columns Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am moving data from Azure Table Storage (source) to Azure Table Storage (Destination)

I have lets say 15 columns in my source but I only want 7 of those in my destination. How can I, or what is the best way to map or query that. I have done some reading into OData queries but that hasn't helped. I am assuming I have to query something similar to a SQL select statement in the copy activity in ADF .

for example: this is the error I get

[image]

Thanks in advance. Please ask for clarification if needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I have lets say 15 columns in my source but I only want 7 of those in
> my destination. How can I, or what is the best way to map or query
> that.

You would use `Query Projection` for that and specify the attributes you want to import using `$select` OData query parameter.

For example if your table has the following attributes: A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6 and B7 and you only want to fetch attributes A1, A2 and A3.

In this case your `$select` query parameter would be like:

```
$select=A1,A2,A3
```

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#supported-query-options.

Comment: Hi, I was doing exactly the same like you are suggesting, but im getting an error. I have edited my question above and added a snip of my error. please refer

Comment: Thanks for sharing more details. I remember seeing a similar question sometime back and if I recall correctly, ADF does not support query projection. You will need to fetch all attributes and do the query projection manually.

Comment: Thank you, when you say "do the query projection manually" what do you mean by that? Where else can I do query projection? (apologies, im very new to table storage)

Comment: And I am new to ADF :). I am guessing that somewhere in your ADF pipeline you will need to tell that you only want to import certain attributes. That's what I meant by doing the query projection manually. HTH.